# how to get the value of special character like #,?,;

Tags: web-services, rest, google-chrome, restful-url

I am using Advanced Rest Client plugin in Google Chrome.

URL: http://localhost:6721/bgs/ujh/data# or data? or data;

method: GET

When I pass this data in my controller I am getting `data` only instead of `data#` or `data?` or `data;`.

Answer (score 0):

You should urlencode the data. # for example would become %23

```
http://localhost:6721/bgs/ujh/data%23
```

Comment: if i encode it like %23 but as a end user pass like this to check he/she don't know the UTF-8 code for each special character

Answer (score 0):

The `#` character indicates a fragment. It is [not sent as part of a HTTP request](https://blog.httpwatch.com/2011/03/01/6-things-you-should-know-about-fragment-urls/). It is only used within the browser to navigate to a part of a page. That's why you are only seeing `data`; the fragment component of the URL is being stripped.

Comment: as you said # used for navigate to a part of page then what about ? and ;

Comment: By themselves they are irrelevant. For the `?` character, it is only relevant if there are query parameters after it. Similarly, the `;` is only relevant when information is appended to it. Your library is chopping off the extra character because of it's irrelevancy. If you had relevant information after those characters, then they should not be truncated.

Comment: Actually it's not my inbuilt library i am using Advanced Rest Client for sending  the request to webservices but i want those special character in my controller side but till now i am not getting the in my controller